# Strange behavior in Visual C++ ShellExecute() function

Tags: mfc, shellexecute

I tried writing a short Visual Studio C++ MFC dialog based application and encounter a strange behavior using `ShellExecute()`.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include "TestShellExecute.h"
#include "TestShellExecuteDlg.h"

// CTestShellExecuteApp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestShellExecuteApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// The one and only CTestShellExecuteApp object
CTestShellExecuteApp theApp;

// CTestShellExecuteApp initialization
BOOL CTestShellExecuteApp::InitInstance()
{
    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    INT_PTR nResponse;
    if (PathFileExists(TEXT("Config.ini")))
        nResponse = IDOK;
    else
    {
        CTestShellExecuteDlg dlg;
        m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
        nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    }
    if (nResponse == IDOK)
        ExecuteApp();
    return FALSE;
}

void CTestShellExecuteApp::ExecuteApp(void)
{
    ShellExecute(NULL, TEXT("open"), TEXT("notepad"), 
        TEXT("test.txt"), NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    return;
}
```

If the file "Config.ini" exists, the code goes directly to ShellExecute() and       Notepad starts fine.

When the file "Config.ini" does not exist, the code opens a dialog box with only OK and Cancel.

After pressed OK, the dialog box returns and runs ShellExecute(). Notepad didn't start. If I comment out the line `m_pMainWnd = &dlg;`, then after the dialog box returns with IDOK, Notepad will start.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: What is m_pMainWnd?

Comment: m_pMainWnd is the main window. As this is a dialogbox application, the dialogbox is the main window. This line is generated by the MFC wizard.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be just a timing issue (in case you set `m_pMainWnd` more cleanup is done). If I add a `Sleep(300);` after `ShellExecute` it works. You should keep in mind that some operations of `ShellExecute` might be done asynchronously (e.g. DDE). I'd consider switching to `ShellExecuteEx` with `SEE_MASK_NOASYNC` or adding a `Sleep` before terminating.

Please also do not forget to initialize COM as clearly stated in the [ShellExecute documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Putting Sleep(300) after ShellExecute() did fix the problem. I tried using ShellExecuteEx() with SEE_MASK_NOASYNC and the behavior is the same as ShellExecute(). Thanks for the answer.